# Load a Windows predefined icon with wxIcon

Tags: windows, icons, wxwidgets, multiplatform

I'm trying to use `IDI_INFORMATION` with wxWidgets 2.8.11 (from wx/version.h) (for `wxMemoryDC::DrawIcon`). But first I have to load the icon: `wxICON(IDI_INFORMATION)` fails, `LoadFile(wxT("IDI_INFORMATION"))` also fails ( but `LoadFile(IDI_INFORMATION)` compiles and crashes, `IDI_INFORMATION` is a fake string pointer too tricky for `wxWidgets`). Hmmm, then I add some `ifdef`s to use Windows API: `::LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_INFORMATION)` works, then `wxIcon::SetHICON`. While `DrawIcon` apparently works, the nasty surprise is that `wxIcon::GetWidth`, `wxIcon::GetHeight` return 0. Hmmm, let's get the size and use `wxIcon::SetSize`. Now it is finally done... wait!, but who's gonna destroy my icon? Not sure, so add the `ifdef`, `SetHICON(NULL)` and  `DestroyIcon`.

The small question: do I have to destroy the icon myself?

The big question: is `wxIcon` entirely useless in this case?

PS After some debugging I discover that `LoadFile(wxT("wxICON_INFORMATION"))` works, wow!, but is it really multi-platform? Do I have read all the wx sources for drawing a standard icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross-platform solution is provided by [wxArtProvider](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_art_provider.html), just use its `GetIcon()` method with `wxART_INFORMATION` argument.

Comment: Wonderful solution, I replaced all the code with just one line.